# Yes/No data type always displaying as True/False - Boolean formatting issues

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have several fields on a form that absolutely will not display a boolean value which is set to display as Yes/No, the dropdown menu is set to only offer Yes/No as options, but no matter what I do, the values displayed on the form always show True/False instead.  Pictures below:
[image: Showing False]
[image: Options with False still showing]
[image: Data type in the table design]
At this point I'm not entirely sure what it is that's causing this, but it's kind of annoying.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but perhaps radio buttons or a checkbox might be a better choice?  Combo boxes should usually have more than just two options in it.

Comment: I probably - if I can't get this fixed - switch to Radio buttons.  But I'd rather fix this if possible.

Comment: Well, then we need to see your datasource; what's the Row Source for the dropdown?

Comment: Row Source is `"Yes";"No"` as a Value List, no Default Value.  It's bound to `BandInstall` which shows all the properties above in the big picture.  EDIT: I know the Table itself shows a default value, but the drop down does not.

Comment: A value list needs a value assigned to the values; try `0,"No",-1,"Yes"` as your row source, with two columns.  That should do it.

Comment: The Format settings must be set on the form, not on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a ComboBox, set the ComboBox properties as follows

In the data section:

```
Control Source = <name of your table or query column>
Row Source Type = Value List
Row Source = -1;Yes;0;No    ' Alternating values and texts.
Bound Column = 1
Limit To List = Yes
```

In the format section

```
Column Count = 2          ' Because we have a value and a text.
Column Widths = 0cm       ' This makes the first column invisible.
```